# Delete operator an item in Javascript with dynamic input

Tags: javascript, object

How can I load the name of an index of an object dynamically so I can delete. When I run `let t = delete secVal.12njjj` am able to delete it but when I change this to `let t = delete secVal.resultS[value.text]` I get an error of `read property of undefined` am following using this document in [mozila dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

```
    var secVal = this.selectedUser[0].filter;
    console.log('Delete this data',resultS[value.text]); //Result = 12njjj(Which is a key of an object)

    let t = delete secVal.resultS[value.text]
    console.log('my t', t)
```

Comment: Console.log secVal.resultS[value.text] -- if it can't find anything the problem is that the value doesn't exist

Comment: If I `console.log(secVal, resultS[value.text])` am able to get an array for the first one and the second a value

Comment: It's `secVal[resultS[value.text]]`, not `secVal.resultS[value.text]`

Comment: @Aplet123 thanks it works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with what @Aplet123 suggested

```
var secVal = this.selectedUser[0].filter;
console.log('Delete this data',resultS[value.text]);

let t = delete secVal[resultS[value.text]]
console.log('my t', t)
console.log('my t', secVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that `secVal` object don't have property `resultS`. 

following code snippet works perfectly
[image]

Comment: This is the problem my object `{a:true,b=true}` what is displayed on the view is different dat that I get from somewhere else depending with the object keys. I use `resultS[value.text]` which converts back to object keys but I get an error on console it does not see it get Value.text instead of the object but when I console log resultS[value.text] without secVal am able to get the correct object keys.